# Notepad++ maximum column

Tags: notepad++

How to set notepad++ maximum column into x (x := max column, eg. 100), I know how to set a vertical edge into 100 columns (in this case just to showing us a sign of 100-th columns), but what I want is something like, if the word is exceed 100 columns, do the linebreak, just like margin of a text. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done automatically (i.e. while typing), but if you resize the Notepad++ window so that it is exactly 100 characters wide, you can *Edit* | *Line Operations* | *Split Lines*.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Replace

- Find What: `^(.{100})(.*)$`
- Replace What: `$1\r\n$2`
- Search Mode Regular Expression

You will need to repeat Replace All until you get 0 occurrence was replaced.